# Decimals not behaving as expected in mongodb aggregation: {$trunc: [1.18 ,2]} in mongodb aggregation returns 1.17

Tags: mongodb, decimal

`{$trunc: [1.18 ,2]}` in mongodb aggregation returns `1.17`. See here in [mongoDB playgound](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xr-is4HnRlS).

When you do `{$trunc: [1.18 ,2]}` you get `1.17999`.

Why is it behaving like this? And what is a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this work around. MongoDB outlines in their [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-monetary-data/) how to deal with decimals to precision.

The way to do it is using [$toDecimal (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDecimal/) like so:

`{$trunc: [ {$toDecimal: 1.18}, 2 ]}`. It returns `NumberDecimal("1.18")`.

[MongoDB explains the purpose of number decimals](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#numberdecimal):

> The mongo shell treats all numbers as 64-bit floating-point double
> values by default. The mongo shell provides the NumberDecimal()
> constructor to explicitly specify 128-bit decimal-based floating-point
> values capable of emulating decimal rounding with exact precision.
> This functionality is intended for applications that handle monetary
> data, such as financial, tax, and scientific computations.